# XCTest : Value not retrieved in NSUserdefaults in UI test Class

Tags: objective-c, swift, ipad, nsuserdefaults, xctest

I am trying to test successful login in app.

In `TestClass` i am fetching value of `Bool` in `NSUserdefault` which is set to true when login is successful in app.

**Code:**
**LoginViewController:ViewController**

```
-(void) onGetSyncStatusChange:(SUPSyncStatusInfo*)info{
....
....

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:true forKey:@"SynchronisationStatus"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

**Issue:** Value is being set true during login but in test class it is 
still giving false(default value).

```
class MarketingPadBoschUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {....}

    override func tearDown() {...}

    func testLoginAndSync(){

    ....

    ....

    XCTAssertTrue(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:   "SynchronisationStatus"),"Synchronisation Issue")

    print("Printing SynchronisationStatus :::   ",UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "SynchronisationStatus"))
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell why value set in code is not getting retrieved in testClass?

Regards,
Smriti

Comment: Can you try initializing user defaults with bundle id of your app ? Also are you testing the async code in the right way ?

Comment: Do you call `onGetSyncStatusChange` in your test?

Comment: @GoodSp33d : Yes, i tried initialising userdefault with app bundle id:     NSUserDefaults *userDef = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName:@"com.infosys.marketingpadbshdevtest2"];
  Still getting false, even after sync is happening. Also i am using XCTwaiter for async tasks.

Comment: @dasdom : onGetSyncStatusChange method, is the part of code that execute when application is launched in test class : XCUIApplication().launch()  , this method gets called when user logs in and sync happens.

Comment: i have checked by putting breakpoint on method onGetSyncStatusChange method() , it is getting called and value is saved true also in userDefault also. But in UITestCase class it cannot be fetched.Giving False as default value.

Answer (score 0):

UItest class doesn't have access to application's internal state. Hence we cannot retrieve UserDefault values, saved in application code,in UITest class. If we wish to access such values we can do so in UnitTest class.

In UITest class, i managed to check sync status by writing own boolean key in userdefault after login and checking status of key in other test functions whenever necessary(This key will be accessible in UITest class only, not outside).